# The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB how to slove this issuse using python spark how to solve this issue in python pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Stage 2 contains a task of very large size (230 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB how to solve this  issues  using python spark please tell me way

Answer (score 0):

Try to repartition the dataframe before using it, like this `df.repartition(100)`